# vuejs - form data checkbox sending [object] instead id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is how I'm making a form with checkbox list:

```
<label class="item" v-for="(item, i) in titulares" :key="item.id">
  <div class="label">
    <div class="title">@{{ item.title || '-' }}</div>
    <div class="m-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="titulares" v-model="atividade.titulares" :value="item" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

And this is how I get the data to send in ajax call

```
data:new FormData(document.getElementById('titulares_form'))
```

The problem is that Form Data is sending objects:

```
titulares: [object Object]
titulares: [object Object]
```

And I want to send the ID's list, like:

```
titulares[]: 10
titulares[]: 12
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the property of the object, in this case, the id property

< input type="checkbox" name="titulares" v-model="atividade.titulares" :value="item.id" />

Comment: doing this it loses `v-model` reference and all checkboxes appears unchecked

Comment: Another approach is to use the JavaScript Map method before sending the data, something like this
titulares.map(x=>x.id), The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function